# LogPlot does not respect PlotRange

Tags: plotting

Using the code below

```
yMin = 10^-11;
yMax = 1;
Show[
 LogPlot[
  Null, {i, 1, 200},
  Frame -> True,
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  PlotRange -> {{0, 200}, {yMin, yMax}},
  ImageSize -> Small
  ],
 Graphics[
  Text[Row[{"yMin=", yMin // N, "  yMax=", yMax // N}], 
   Scaled[{0.5, 0.5}]]]
 ]
```

I generated a series of plots with different values of `yMax`:

[image: series of LogPlots]

**My Problem:** I cannot get Mathematica to place a label at position `yMax` *and* one at position `yMin`. Mathematica places a label in only one of the two positions and leaves the other one orphan. Which corner gets the label shifts as `yMax` changes. I don't want to write my own tick marks manually. I want the y-Axis to be labelled as the x-Axis, with labels at the two ends.

This is with Mathematica 12.1.1 on Mac OS 10.15.6

Answer (score 1):

You don't show the code that you used for the labels at `yMin` and `yMax`. You probably just need to include the options [`PlotRangeClipping`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRangeClipping.html) and [`ImagePadding`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding.html).

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Manipulate[
 LogPlot[Null, {i, 1, 200},
  Frame -> True,
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  PlotRange -> {{0, 200}, {yMin, yMax}},
  ImageSize -> Small,
  Epilog -> {Text[Row[{"yMin=", yMin // N, "  yMax=", yMax // N}],
     Scaled[{0.5, 0.5}]],
    Text["label at yMin", Scaled[{0.5, 0.0}]],
    Text["label at yMax", Scaled[{0.5, 1.0}]]},
  PlotRangeClipping -> False,
  ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, 10}}],
 {{yMin, 1.*^-11}, 1.*10^Range[-11, -6]},
 {{yMax, 100}, 10^Range[0, 6]}]
```

[image]

Comment: You could also use `... Text["label at yMin", {100, Log[yMin]}], Text["label at yMax", {100, Log[yMax]}], ...` instead of the `Scaled` coordinates.

Comment: Maybe I need to explain my question better: As you see in your graph, you specified yMax100 but the highest tick label on the graph is 10. I want the number "100" printed as a tick label at the upper left corner just as 10^-11 is printed at the bottom left.